# Setup Pseudo Distributed / Single Node Setup Apache Hadoop 2.2

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have installed Apache Hadoop 2.2 as Single Node Cluster. When I am trying to execute giraph example, it ends up with error "LocalJobRunner, you cannot run in split master/worker mode since there is only 1 task at a time".

I was going through forums, and I found that I can update mapred-site.xml to have 4 mappers. I tried that but still no help. I came across, one more forum were I can change single node setup to behave as pseudo distributed mode and it resolved the issue.

Can someone please let me know, which config files do I need to change to get single node setup behave as pseudo distributed mode.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to renZzz answer,  You also need to  check that if you can ssh to the localhost without a passphrase:

```
 $ ssh localhost
```

If you cannot ssh to localhost without a passphrase, execute the following commands:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Following link can help you- https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleNodeSetup.html

Answer (score 0):

for my first setup, I followed some manuals, but surely the best one for single node setup, was the pdf [Apache Hadoop YARN_sample](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CDoQFjAC&url=http://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Apache.Hadoop.YARN_.Sample.pdf&ei=UpCxUuXeNtK7hAfG84GwDg&usg=AFQjCNFofynB9IObABFq1yKgtwXf9_DkAw&sig2=nQVA7IPyTGt-wTr1uYEWVA&bvm=bv.58187178,d.ZG4). I recommond you to use this manual step by step

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that the number of workers is one. Then, you need to configure Giraph not to split workers and master via:

```
giraph.SplitMasterWorker=false
```

You can either set it in giraph-site.xml or pass via command
line option:

```
 -ca giraph.SplitMasterWorker=false
```

Ref:
https://www.mail-archive.com/user@giraph.apache.org/msg01631.html